# vscode: update to stylistic sets using font ligatures with Fira Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

See [October, 2019 Release Notes - stylistic sets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_font-feature-settings).

> **Font feature settings**
>
> There is now more fine grained control over the font features. When
>   configuring `"editor.fontLigatures": true`, VS Code would turn on
>   `liga` and `calt`. But some fonts have more settings, such as
>   stylistic sets used by Fira Code.
>
> We now allow these font features to be explicitly controlled, for
>   example:
>
> `"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",`
>
> `"editor.fontLigatures": true,`
>
> ```
> "[javascript]": {  
>    "editor.fontLigatures": "'ss02', 'ss19'",
> },
> ```

This is what stylistic sets can do. (See https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#stylistic-sets.)

[image: Fira Code v2 stylistic sets].

I was already using Fira Code, so I thought I could download version 2 of the font and add the following lines to the editor settings.

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",  
  "editor.fontLigatures":"'zero', 'ss02', 'ss03', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'calt'",
```

I was getting strange results: The *zero* style would work, but previously working ligatures stopped working; other sets didn't work at all.

How do I get Fira Code version 2 stylistic sets working in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that the stylistic sets would work better, but not perfectly, if I disabled this setting:

```
"editor.letterSpacing": 0.2,
```

I filed an issue with vscode, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84018 where I learned that you should add the `calt` set to your ligature settings ala

```
"editor.fontLigatures":"'zero', 'ss02', 'ss03', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'calt'",
```

Thanks to alexandrudima.

And then I noticed a number of people were having similar issues, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84917

Two important points to get stylistic sets working:

1. In your OS font manager, **uninstall older versions** of Fira Code if you were using it before first, and then install Fira Code v2.  And **restarting** the OS and vscode afterwards is probably necessary.
2. You will almost certainly need to **add `calt` to your list** of whatever new sets you wish to use just to get other sets working.