# What is the VSCODE extension/theme/symbolset used to display formatted/actually arrows in arrow functions syntax

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I have come through many tutorials and screenshots of JS Code in Visual Studio Code editor consisting of formatted arrows seen for arrow functions.

Which extension/theme/symbol set is required to get that like in the screenshot?

[image: VSCode Editor]

Comment: You are looking for a font that supports ligatures, like Fira Code among others.  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965575/vscode-update-to-stylistic-sets-using-font-ligatures-with-fira-code

Answer (score 54):

What you are looking for is a font designed for coding called

> Fira Code

It's one of the most popular fonts among programmers

It will turn => into that arrow shape you saw and do other stuff

[Fira Code on Github](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)

There are instructions on how to use in vs code

Comment: See comment above.

Comment: Not only fira code its required, only works  for sublimetext

Comment: Installed but not showing in file

Answer (score 30):

Install the FiraCode font from https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases

1. Install the fonts
2. Go into VsCode settings and search font
3. In the Text Editor tab, replace the font with "Fira Code" (Windows) and  "FiraCode" (Mac)
   OR

Add this in the settings.json:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code Medium, monospace",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace",
"editor.fontSize": 13
```

Comment: Best reply with steps! Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful! Tks a million!

Answer (score 10):

You have to also set `editor.fontLigatures` to `true`
when using fonts with font ligatures.

Answer (score 7):

Two Options

Ctrl+P > search & edit for settings.json > add below

> ```
>  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
>  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
>  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
>  "editor.fontSize": 12
> ```

OR

1. Download [Google Fire Code Font Family](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code)
2. Open VsCode > settings > add `Fira Code` in Font Family input

Note: If needed, restart VsCode

All the best

Comment: I had everything working nicely with the fira font but couldn't get the arrows to dress up. This `fontLigatures` property did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful! Tks a million!

Answer (score 2):

install font : Fira Code (https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases)

or

install font : cascadia-code  (https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps.

- Download this
  https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases/download/6.2/Fira_Code_v6.2.zip
- Unzip it. In the ttf folder, select all and right click to install.
- Open VS Code, go to settings.json (vs code settings => **Ctrl + ,**).
- Add these at lowest of the JSON

> "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
> "editor.fontLigatures": true,

- Save and Restart VS Code

Note: Helpful references

https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions
https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Installing

Answer (score 0):

You can install **One Dark Pro** extension which gives you very similar experience.

Apart from this I use

- Beautify
- ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native
- Prettier

Comment: I installed One Dark Pro but it didn't change that arrow icon with the icon they're showing. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Manage -> Setting -> open json

```
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
 "editor.fontFamily": "'cascadia code',Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
```

font Link: https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

VSCode tutorial:

Open settings.json, then put this in the json:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code Regular",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to download any fonts, you can simply just install the following extension in VSCode: **[Fira Code and Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aleleba.fira-code-material-icon-theme)**

Do not forget to add the following lines to `settings.json`

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "fira-code-material-icon-theme",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot how to set these fonts etc then finally I found very easy solution: [FiraCode font extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SeyyedKhandon.firacode)