# How to enable FiraCode ligatures AND stylistic sets at the same time in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

My question is simple. To enable FiraCode ligatures in VScode, you must add this line to `settings.json`:

`"editor.fontLigatures": true`

To enable a stylistic set (i.e. for sans serif lowercase 'r' or dotted zero), you have to add this line to the same file:

`"editor.fontLigatures": "'ss01', 'zero'"`

This results in a conflict because you can't have 2 properties of the same name in JSON. One of the settings will be ignored. Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: if the doc does not provide a solution to this ambiguity file a bug report

Comment: Just use the one with the sets.  And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965575/vscode-update-to-stylistic-sets-using-font-ligatures-with-fira-code?r=SearchResults&s=1|114.0170 for more info.

Comment: ahh, I'm wondering why they never mentioned `'calt'` in stylistic sets instructions. That did the job. Thank you!