# How can i fix this? my editor fontligatures is not enabled

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baHDr.png)

i am using vscode but for some reason my fontligatures is not enabled so anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58965575/836330

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello This setting is used to enable font modification settings. However, before modifying, you must download the relevant fonts on your computer. I found a link to download：[enter link description here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)， After downloading, install it, and you can see it in the windows control panel. Then revise where you said it!
Hope helpful!

Comment: thank you for your response. That was helpful and finally fixed that problem.

Comment: That's wonderful! Hah, If you solve it successfully, could you please give my answer a mark for it's my first times? :)