# How to make Fira Code Stylistic Settings cv24 and cv31 work in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, ligature, fira-code

In my settings.json I have the following lines.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code SemiBold'",
"editor.fontLigatures": "'cv24', 'cv31', 'zero', 'ss02', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'ss09', 'calt', 'liga'",
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aTud.png)

All of the Stylistic Settings I have tried work except for cv24 and cv31 which are supposed to make `/=` look like `≠`, and make the parentheses rounder according to [the Fira Code github](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode). Does anyone know how to get these ligatures displaying correctly?

From reading about similar problems (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965575/vscode-update-to-stylistic-sets-using-font-ligatures-with-fira-code) and [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/892)) I have added `'calt'` to the list of settings, and I do not have `"editor.letterSpacing"` enabled. I also made sure I didn't have an old version of fira installed as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/How-to-enable-stylistic-sets).

Comment: Probably not an issue, but I only have `"Fira Code"` not `"'Fira Code'"` - note the extra single quotes.  Easy enough to remove them and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: That did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  And if so did you follow the `Unblock` instructions at https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Installing#windows.? Also just try `"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code'",` and ` "editor.fontWeight": "600",` or similar and your ligatures setting.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know why, but if I set `"editor.fontWeight": "550",` - at least `550` then those stylistic sets start to work.  Anything less than `550` and they don't.  Do you see that too?  Using this: `"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code'"` and your `fontLigatures setting.

Comment: I am on windows and I just reinstalled the font trying to follow your first suggestion but none of the .ttf files had the checkbox to unblock the files. But Reinstalling the font seems to have fixed the issues. The ligatures also work at all the weights I tried and using SemiBold. I guess I should have tried the classic turn it off and back on again sooner.

Comment: Yes, I now have it working with `"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code SemiBold",` and the `fontWeight` setting seems to be irrelevant then.  A few reloads of vscode helped.  I did have the `Unblock` option at the bottom of the properties dialog.